# nullable model field in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linqpad

got a exception when exec the query in LinqPad

```
var allNewsInADay= (from t in Tnews where t.SendTime.Value.Year==2012 && 
    t.SendTime.Value.Month==8  && t.SendTime.Value.Day==20 select t);
allNewsInADay.Dump();
```

> Exception: The member access 'System.DateTime Value' is not supported

if use .HasValue property: `NotSupportedException: The member access 'Boolean HasValue' is not supported`

--
i use MySql
and my purpose is to get all records in a specific day.

Comment: Just a tip: `rslt` is not very readable. Use real words instead such as `result` or more specific to make clear what kind of data you are retrieving such as `var news = (from...`

Comment: DateTime.Value is private. it's Nullable<DateTime>.Value that is accessible. How is your DateTime null then? DBNull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rslt= (from t in Tnews 
           where t.SendTime.HasValue 
              && t.SendTime.Value.Year==2012 
              && t.SendTime.Value.Month==8  
              && t.SendTime.Value.Day==20 
           select t);
```

or

```
var someDate = new DateTime(2012,8,20);
var rslt= (from t in Tnews 
           where t.SendTime.HasValue  
              && t.SendTime.Value.Date==someDate 
           select t);
```

will help?

upd: you tried bad. just ran this:

```
class Program
{
    public class TNews
    {
        public DateTime? SendTime { get; set; }
        public string Id;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tnews = new TNews[]
        {
            new TNews { SendTime = new DateTime(2012,8,20), Id="2012-08-20" },
            new TNews { SendTime = new DateTime(2012,8,20,12,20,0), Id="2012-08-20 12:20" },
            new TNews { SendTime = new DateTime(2012,8,21), Id="2012-08-21" },
            new TNews { SendTime = null, Id="null" },
        };

        var someDate = new DateTime(2012, 8, 20);
        var rslt = (from t in tnews
                    where t.SendTime.HasValue 
                       && t.SendTime.Value.Date == someDate
                    select t);

        foreach (var t in rslt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

output is:

```
2012-08-20
2012-08-20 12:20
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: NotSupportedException: The member access 'Boolean HasValue' is not supported

Comment: is your SendTime defined as nullable? or you receive this from datebase?

Comment: just not supported by `linqPad`... i changed my connection to a mapped .dll, it works now

Answer (score 4):

you can use [SqlFunctions.DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) instead

usage :

```
where SqlFunctions.DatePart(t.SendTime, "yy") == 2012 &&
      SqlFunctions.DatePart(t.SendTime, "mm") == 8 &&
      SqlFunctions.DatePart(t.SendTime, "dd") == 20)
```

or

```
var dt = new DateTime(2012, 8, 20);

...
where t.SendTime == dt
```

or [canonical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563%28v=vs.100%29) (supported by all providers)

```
 where EntityFunctions.Year(t.SendTime) == 2012
```

Maybe a null check
`t.SendTime != null` (or `t.SendTime.HasValue`) as first predicate

would be necessary

or just remove `Value` !

Comment: NotSupportedException 
The method 'DatePart' is not supported

Comment: @kevin take a look at edited answer : Canonical functions part, maybe

Comment: 'System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions' does not contain a definition for 'Year'

Comment: @Kevin use System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityFunctions

Comment: same as .Value property .HasValue property is not supported too.

Comment: @Kevin you mean you've got an error while using `where System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityFunctions.Year(t.SendTime) == 2012` ? What version of framework are you using ?

Comment: @Kevin maybe just try to remove "Value" in your query.

Comment: .Value just not supported by `linqPad`... i changed my connection to a mapped .dll, it works now